# How to mount (and keep) a NTFS HDD with RW permissions

Tags: hard-drive, permissions, ntfs, raspberry-pi-os

I have the Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, I've installed Raspbian OS using NOOBS. Everything works fine until I plug in my NTFS HDD via USB, the hard drive is detected and mounted automatically, but with RO permissions. Apparently I can just remount with RW permission `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda2 /media/pi/Media/` so I do that and it works perfectly.. until I reboot, after the reboot the HDD simply disappears. I don't know how to get it back without reinstalling Raspbian. So is there a better way to get RW permissions that doesn't hide the HDD after a reboot or is there a way to get the HDD back after a reboot. Thanks for any help.

Edit:
I have just reinstalled Raspbian so the drive is back (RO again)

fstab:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0

/dev/mmcblk0p6  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2

/dev/mmcblk0p7  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1

\# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here

\#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

sudo blkid output:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="RECOVERY" LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="C5FC-4267" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="000626e2-01"

/dev/mmcblk0p5: LABEL="SETTINGS" UUID="7b4bed67-ec0b-4c8e-868c-d285cbd45a43" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000626e2-05"

/dev/mmcblk0p6: LABEL_FATBOOT="boot" LABEL="boot" UUID="EE87-DFD2" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="000626e2-06"

/dev/mmcblk0p7: LABEL="root" UUID="cf0274c5-98ea-499d-8f2a-68ec2a3b2543" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000626e2-07"

/dev/sda2: LABEL="Media" UUID="46205A22205A196F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="d526499e-bf03-44ba-b1d7-65bf0d270241"

/dev/mmcblk0: PTUUID="000626e2" PTTYPE="dos"

/dev/sda1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="22633a78-bf20-4224-9917-98f0745768bd"
```

Edit 2:

This is the new output of blkid:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="RECOVERY" LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="C5FC-4267" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="000626e2-01"

/dev/mmcblk0p5: LABEL="SETTINGS" UUID="7b4bed67-ec0b-4c8e-868c-d285cbd45a43" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000626e2-05"

/dev/mmcblk0p6: LABEL_FATBOOT="boot" LABEL="boot" UUID="EE87-DFD2" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="000626e2-06"

/dev/mmcblk0p7: LABEL="root" UUID="cf0274c5-98ea-499d-8f2a-68ec2a3b2543" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000626e2-07"

/dev/mmcblk0: PTUUID="000626e2" PTTYPE="dos"
```

This is the new fstab file:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0

/dev/mmcblk0p6  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2

/dev/mmcblk0p7  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1

UUID="46205A22205A196F" /media/pi/Media ntfs-3g auto,nofail,noatime,rw,user 0 0

\# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here

\#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

Comment: What have you got in `/etc/fstab`? Can you also edit your post and add the output from a `sudo blkid` command (with the drive mounted manually).

Comment: @Dougie Done, I haven't been able to mount the HDD manually, either it mounts automatically with RO perm or not at all, the edit is with the drive mounted automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have kinda fixed the problem. Once I shut down I have to unplug both the pi and the hdd's power and remount on startup by adding `@reboot sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point` to `sudo crontab -e`. This is obviously not ideal but at this point it's good enough for me. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1):

Edit /etc/fstab and add

```
UUID="46205A22205A196F" /media/pi/Media/ ntfs-3g auto,nofail,noatime,rw,user    0   0
```

and it should mount automatically at bootup. Bootup won't fail if the drive is not plugged in because of the `nofail` option.

Comment: I did this and it has disappeared again, I'll edit and add the new output of blkid and my new fstab file

Comment: After power cycling the pi and the hdd its back, but its still read only.

Comment: Then stick it in a Windows system and check the filesystem.